# What is a concise way to inform the compiler of the specifc type with multiple implementations of a generic trait?

Tags: generics, types, casting, rust, traits

I've come across an odd type inference problem that has me scratching my head a bit.

I'm implementing a generic trait on a struct for multiple types. I started with `&str`:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    baz: &'a str,
}

trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> T;
}

impl<'a> Foo<&'a str> for Bar<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'a str {
        self.baz
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_str_a() {
        let bar = Bar { baz: "asd" };
        assert_eq!("asd", bar.foo());
    }
}
```

This works — the problem comes when I add another implementation for the `u8` type:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
    baz: &'a str,
}

trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> T;
}

impl<'a> Foo<&'a str> for Bar<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'a str {
        self.baz
    }
}

impl<'a> Foo<u8> for Bar<'a> {
    fn foo(&self) -> u8 {
        8
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_str_a() {
        let bar = Bar { baz: "asd" };
        assert_eq!("asd", bar.foo());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_u8() {
        let bar = Bar { baz: "asd" };
        assert_eq!(8 as u8, bar.foo());
    }
}
```

In this case, I get the following error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `Bar<'_>: Foo<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:28:31
   |
28 |         assert_eq!("asd", bar.foo());
   |                               ^^^
```

If I store the value in a variable it works:

```
let foo: &str = bar.foo();
```

In my production code, I do a lot of asserts and it would make things a bit messy. I've also tried `bar.foo() as &str` but that also fails as the compiler doesn't know `bar.foo()`'s type either. I'm trying to find a concise way for the compiler to know the type.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the type parameter to the trait using a *turbofish* (`::<>`):

```
assert_eq!("asd", Foo::<&str>::foo(&bar));
```

You could also use [fully-qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation) to disambiguate which trait the method belongs to:

```
// This is "type-qualified" and equivalent to `Foo::<&str>::foo(&bar)`
assert_eq!("asd", <_ as Foo<&str>>::foo(&bar));

// This is "fully qualified"
assert_eq!("asd", <Bar as Foo<&str>>::foo(&bar));
```

Comment: @Shepmaster, it is not a case of ambiguous `Type`. It is a case of ambiguous `Trait`, fully qualified syntax thus is not required. `Trait::method()` is a shortened form of `<Type as Trait>::method()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you... UFCS was poorly named and was renamed to FQS. Your original answer stated that OP should use UFCS (thus FQS), but now your comment states that OP shouldn't use FQS.

Comment: Your first comment states that `Trait::method()` syntax is not FQS nor UFCS. I've taken it for "FQS is a specific name for `<Type as Trait>::method()` syntax and `Trait::method()` syntax has other name" and answered accordingly.

Comment: In fact both `Trait::method()` (or `Trait::<T1, T2, ... TN>::method()`) and `<Type as Trait>::method()` (or `<Type as Trait<T1, T2, ... TN>>::method()`) are FQS. As stated in the book: "However, we’re allowed to leave out any part of this syntax that Rust is able to figure out from other information in the program."

Comment: I'm making the claim that `Trait::method()` is *not* FQS, I believe that only the forms with angle brackets are FQS (`<Trait>::method` / `<Type as Trait>::method`). The code in the answer is just using a turbofish to fill in type parameters. Likewise, `iterator.collect::<Foo>` isn't using FQS.

Comment: The fact is `Trait::<T>::method(receiver)` does exactly the same thing as `<_ as Trait<T>>::method(receiver)`, but I don't insist on calling it FQS.

Comment: OK, I've applied my pedantic changes. ;-)