# How to use a method in Rust without the "use" keyword?

Tags: syntax, rust

I am learning Rust coming from a Java background. In Java, I would commonly `import java.util.ArrayList;`. As far as I understand, this was a convenience to prevent needing to put `java.util.` preceding every occurrence of `ArrayList`.

Consider the following Rust:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    print!("Hello World!");
    // Let's flush the Buffer
    io::stdout().flush().expect("Oh No!");
}
```

If the first `use` is removed, `io` is no longer specified. We can fix this by adding `std::` before `io`.

The program now reads like this:

```
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    print!("Hello World!");
    // Let's flush the Buffer
    std::io::stdout().flush().expect("Oh No!");
}
```

What catches my interest is the second `use` - It is required to use the `flush` method on stdout. This makes my Java analogy very unhappy - I expect `flush` to be a part of the "`stdout` thing", and if I have the thing I can use the methods - but that is clearly not the case here.

Is it possible to write the above program without the second `use`? If so, what is the syntax to fully specify `flush`?

What is going on?

---

## Solution

**Solved** by some helpful comments below. The linked questions, while not the same question, do have similar answers.

The line in question:

`std::io::stdout().flush().expect("Oh no!");`

In my experience, `stdout.flush()` implies that `flush` is a function within stdout. In Java, stdout would be an object, passed to flush "behind-the-scenes" as `this`. In Python, it would be explicitly in the method signature as `self`.

In Rust, in this situation, `stdout` is being passed to `flush` via dot notation. To fully specify `flush`, `stdout` must be passed in the "traditional" way, within `flush`'s parenthesis.

In short, `Object.method()` is equivalent to `method(Object)`. (At least here - I am still learning, and may be very wrong.)

To fully specify both `stdout` and `flush`, I use the following:

`std::io::Write::flush(&mut std::io::stdout()).expect("Oh no!");`

Looking further, the first argument to `expect` is "self", furthering the `x.y() == y(x)` idea. Translating the above into y(x) format completely, we arrive at the very complicated:

```
std::result::Result::expect(
    std::io::Write::flush(
        &mut std::io::stdout()
    ),
    "Oh no!"
);
```

This has been enlightening. Thank you all, and I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: In your case, the duplicate suggests `std::io::Write::flush(&mut std::io::stdout())`. The fully qualified syntax (where you specify both the trait and the type) would look similar to `<std::io::Stdout as std::io::Write>::flush(&mut std::io::stdout)`.

Comment: You may also find [What is a concise way to inform the compiler of the specifc type with multiple implementations of a generic trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48263001/3650362) interesting.

Comment: @trentcl, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!